# Delete rows from postgres database contain string/sentence

Tags: replace, postgresql

I would like to know how to delete entire rows in a postgres table that contain a particular string in the `title` column. So if the string is:

```
it is a sunny day
```

How can I issue a command in postgres to remove this row from the table completely. For example, the following row would be deleted:

```
12, I woke up and to my surprise it is a sunny day, 54645646,
```

Also, I would like it to ignore case as the string could be a mixture of capital and lower case letters (i.e. the case my vary throughout the table). Any help appreciated.

I've tried:

```
DELETE FROM mytable where title like 'it is a sunny day'
```

But no records were updated despite the fact that I know there are a number of lines with this string in.

Comment: Did you even try googling for this? The PostgreSQL online docs tell you exactly how to do this...

Comment: Yes I've edited my question to show what i've tried

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think it belongs on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @JeffSchaller note that the [dba.se]'s help center says "but, dba.se is *not* the right place to ask questions about [b]asic SQL - ask on [so]".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By LOWER function, you can search case insensitively your string.

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE LOWER(title) LIKE '%it is a sunny day%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You're part way there. You need to use a regexp pattern, not just a string, to search only a part of the entry string, and the ILIKE keyword for case insensitivity. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html for details (that URL valid only for 9.x versions of PostgreSQL).

Comment: Thanks for the link, i'm looking through it, but it's not the easiest type of information to decipher when you are first starting out!